# How can I mount a SFTP server that needs a PGP key, with nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

I use my PGP key as ssh private key to log into almost all my ssh servers (thanks to gpg-agent). I now want to connect to it with SFTP via nautilus, but every time I try I get a 'Access denied' popup.

From what I gathered through my research, Nautilus use sshfs (it probably changed, most of the article I saw was dated 2010, and it wasn't installed on my machine). So I tried and I can mount it via sshfs, but when I try again from nautilus I still get a 'Permission denied' popup.

I found a way to get the log, and effectively, it's a key issue :

```
sftp: stderr: jangberry@<MyServerIP>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

While ssh-agent haven't any key and the only key gpg-agent may use is authorized on this server

Comment: Do you mean your private ssh key?

Comment: @user3417815 I mean I use a key from my gpg keyring as a shh key... (I edited the post to clarify about it)